# nested foreach loop when the inner loop array has more than one field

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

what changes are to be made to view and the viewmodel in the following example if the children array has two more fields 
"child age" and "weight".

view:

```
 <h2>People</h2>
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
<li>
    <div>
        <span data-bind="text: name"> </span> has <span data-bind='text: children().length'>&nbsp;</span> children:    
    </div>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: children">
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text: $data"> </span>                
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

viewmodel:

```
var Person = function(name, children) {
this.name = name;
this.children = ko.observableArray(children);

this.addChild = function() {
    this.children.push("New child");
}.bind(this);
 }

var viewModel = {
people: [
    new Person("Annabelle", ["Arnie", "Anders", "Apple"]),
    new Person("Bertie", ["Boutros-Boutros", "Brianna", "Barbie", "Bee-bop"]),
    new Person("Charles", ["Cayenne", "Cleopatra"])
    ],
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional properties to the children array by making it an array of objects instead of just an array of strings like so:

```
new Person("Annabelle", [
    {Name: "Arnie", weight: 25, age: 2}, 
    {Name: "Anders", weight: 45, age: 5}, 
    {Name: "Apple", weight: 29, age: 2}])
```

and the html change like so:

```
<span data-bind="text: $data.Name"></span>    
<ul>
    <li data-bind="text: $data.weight +'lbs. '"/>
    <li data-bind="text: $data.age + ' years'"/>
</ul>
```

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smurphy/p7FHd/) with a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the children would need to be objects. You could potentially reuse `Person` if you intend for it to also contain those properties.

```
[{name:"Arnie", age: 1, weight: 2}]
```

Then you bind to the properties:

```
<span data-bind="text: name"> </span> 
<span data-bind="text: age"> </span> 
<span data-bind="text: weight"> </span>
```

Furthermore, you could use the `'as' aliasing` feature of the [foreach](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) binding to make the HTML clearly reflect where the information is coming from

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: {data: children, as 'child'}">
```

The bindings for the child properties would take on the format

```
<span data-bind="text: child.name"> </span>
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/77Q4W/) for reference.